# Integration by Substitution

Tags: integration

Question:

> Use the substitution $u=\tan x$ to find $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\large \frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\tan^{n+2}x + \tan^{n}x\right)dx$.
>
> Using the above result, find the exact value of $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\large \frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\tan^9x+5\tan^7x+5\tan^5x+\tan^3x\right)$$

Taking $\tan^n x$ as common, $\tan^{n+2}x+\tan^nx=\tan^n x(\tan^2x +1)=\tan^nx\cdot{\sec^2x}$.

I substituted $\displaystyle u=\tan x \rightarrow dx=\frac{1}{\sec^2x}du$ and the new limits are $0$ and $1$.

By substitution $$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\large \frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\tan^{n+2}x+\tan^nx\right)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\left(u^n\right)du=\left[\frac{1}{n+1}u^{n+1}\right]_{0}^{1}$$

Applying the limits, the answer is $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\large \frac{\pi}{4}}\left(\tan^{n+2}x+\tan^nx\right)=\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Now how do I do the second part using this answer?

Comment: It's been 3 Months, I hop you can Fix $\LaTeX$, [Refer This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $$\displaystyle \small\tan^9x+5\tan^7x+5\tan^5x+\tan^3x=(\tan^9x+\tan^7x)+4(\tan^7x+\tan^5x)+(\tan^5x+\tan^3x)$$

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea you mentioned for the first part ($\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\tan x)^n \cdot \sec^2 x \, dx$) seems fine. For the next integral, we split the given integral into two integrals, namely $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\tan^9 u +\tan^3 u)\, du+ 5\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\tan^7 u +\tan^5 u) \, du$.

If we wish to compute $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\tan^7 u +\tan^5 u) \, du$, this is a direct application of the previously derived fact for $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\tan x)^n \cdot \sec^2 x \, dx$. And, for obtaining $\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\tan^9 u +\tan^3 u) \, du$, if $J=\int_{0}^{\pi/4}(\tan^9 u +\tan^3 u) \, du$ - note (if $u=\arctan v$) then $J=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{v^9+v^3}{1+v^2} \, dv$, or $J=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+v^2}v^3(1+v^6) \, dv$. Now, note $\frac{1+v^6}{1+v^2}=1-v^2+v^4$, so $J=\int_{0}^{1}v^3(1-v^2+v^4) \, dv$. Thus $J=\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{8}$, or $J=\frac{5}{24}$.